# How to define a path for Tiles configurer?

Tags: spring-mvc, web-deployment, apache-tiles

My Spring application can not start because the path of the tiles.xml file that was working fine until now can not be reached. I can deploy it locally, but when I create a .war to upload it to the server it gives me the error.

Can anybody tell how much path should I define not to crash on this error when I am deploying the application?
(And why).

This is my qualified name is... path: /VotaIdeas/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tiles.xml

> 2018-01-25 09:43:26.015 ERROR 2587 --- [-nio-80-exec-77] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>     : Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesCon
>   figurer' defined in com.caveofprogramming.App: Invocation of init method failed; nested exceptio
>   n is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [**/WEB-INF/tiles.xml**]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initiali
>   zeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELE
>   ASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreate
>   Bean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE
>   ]

... and here is the tiles configurer in App.java:

```
@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();

    String[] defs = {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"};

    tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(defs);

    return tilesConfigurer;
}
```

[image: Files structure]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tiles.version>3.0.5</tiles.version>
</properties>

<groupId>com.caveofprogramming</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>20160628.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: .war file]

[image: left works, right does not work]

[image: Web Deployment Assembly]

Comment: Are you absoultelly sure that `WEB-INF/tiles.xml` has been packaged to the war and exactly just under `WEB-INF`?

Comment: You are right. It is not! It was before :-( What have I done without knowing?
 How can I get the tiles.xml file back on the .war file?

Comment: Should I just move src/main/webapp/WEB-INF  to src/main/java? Thanks Mikel

Comment: Now that you shared your project structure, I guess that what is happening is that `Webcontent/WEB-INF` may be overwriting `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. if you are packaging with maven, have a look at the `maven-war-plugin` to see which folder is being useb as webapp base folder

Comment: Sorry, any idea how to do that? Can I drag and drop the folder in a place? (i'm quite lost) Thanks again Mikel.

Comment: Open your project's `pom.xml` and search for `maven-war-plugin`. There must be a property identifying which is your project's base web folder. You could edit your question and show your pom.xml's content. Another thing... how do you know my real name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163906/discussion-between-jorge-m-nures-and-jlumietu).